# How to get instance of google chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I want to get instance of google chart.
Since I use ng-google-chart, I can't save the instance when it is created.

I know the id of chart's div.
Can I get the instance?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by the instance? In the HTML code, if you are doing your binding like this `<div google-chart chart="myChart">`, the instance should be in `myChart`.

Comment: Created by 'new google.visualization.~~~', internally

Comment: you might get a better response if you post some code / provide an example -- pretty sure you cannot access the chart, just with an id from the div

Answer (score 0):

If you mean [this](https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart), then you can get the chart instance, by using the `agc-before-draw`  directive. It should look something like

```
<div google-chart chart="chartObj" agc-before-draw="beforeDrawHandler(chartWrapper)">
</div>
```

and then using the chartWrapper, you can access the chart instance, with `chartWrapper.getChart()`. Just make sure you use version 0.1.0